# about a maximal normal subgroup of a $p$ group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

i'm studying bhattacharya's basic algebra. it introduces the concept of the group action in chapter 4 and proves the class equation. and derives simple properties of $p$ group using the equation. the author proves the thm stating :

"Let $G$ be a finite group of order $p^{n}$, where $p$ is a prime $n$ is a natural number. If $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, then $H$ is a properly contained in $N(H)$; hence, if $H$ is a subgroup of order $p^{n-1}$, then $H$ is normal in $G$".

and the author starts the proof by saying: " Let $K$ be a maximal normal group of $G$ contained in $H$......"

Well how do you know $H$ contains a maximal normal group of $G$? This seems nontrivial to me......any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can approach this from a "chain" perspective. Consider all of the normal subgroups contained in $H$. Then if you order these by inclusion, eventually you'll have to stop since $H$ is finite. These "final" subgroups are the maximal normal subgroups.

Comment: how do you guarantee inclusion relation among normal subgroups of H?

Comment: A normal subgroup H of G is 'Maximal' if H is not G, and only normal subgroups of G containing H are G and H

Comment: You can't say that all of the normal subgroups are in the same chain. You will have in general different chains of inclusions going on. However each chain will necessarily terminate since $H$ is finite. Pick any one of those "final" normal subgroups and that is a maximal subgroup of $H$. Note that any of those will satisfy your definition since there will not be any other normal subgroups in $H$ which strictly contain them.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\rm P$ be a subgroup property (e.g. proper, nontrivial, normal, central, characteristic, finite-index, and so on). I picked up this cool term from [GroupProps](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_property). Then:

- a "$\rm P$ maximal subgroup" is a maximal subgroup which is $\rm P$, whereas
- a "maximal $\rm P$ subgroup" is a subgroup which is maximal *among* $\rm P$ subgroups.

The set of all subgroups of a group $G$ forms a partially ordered set ${\cal L}(G)$ under inclusion (in fact it forms a lattice). Any subset $X\subseteq{\cal L}(G)$ inherits the partial order and becomes a poset in its own right, but $X$ may not contain any maximal elements. An element of a poset is *maximal* if it is not less than any other element. In general there may be no maximal elements or multiple maximal elements, and a maximal element may not be comparable with every other element.

If $G$ is finite though, then ${\cal L}(G)$ is finite and so is the set of $\rm P$ groups (whatever the property $\rm P$ is), and thus there *must* be at least one maximal element. So there is a subgroup of $G$ which is maximal among $\rm P$ groups. Of course this situation is ${\rm P}=$ being a normal subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

> If $H$ is a proper subgroup of the **finite** group $G$ then there is a *maximal* subgroup of $G$ containing $H$.

Note that a subgroup M of $G$ is called *maximal* if $M \neq G$ and the only subgroups of $G$ that contain $M$ are $M$ and $G$) Let's prove the statement.

*Proof.* Consider the set $S=\{K\leq G: K\neq G, H\leq K\}$. This is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(G)$ and so is partially ordered by $\subseteq$ and is finite since $G$ is finite. If $S=\varnothing$, then $H$ itself is the maximal subgroup. Now suppose that $S$ is not empty and that no maximal subset containing $H$ exists. Then there is an element $K_{0} \in S$. Since $K_{0}$ is not maximal there exists an element $K_{1} \in S$, such that $K_{0} \leq K_{1}$ and $K_{0} \neq K_{1}$. Similarly since $K_{1}$ is not maximal there exists an element $K_{2} \in S$ such that $K_{0}\leq K_{1} \leq K_{2}$ and $K_{1} \neq K_{2}$. Thus, we may construct an infinite ascending chain of subgroups $K_{0}<K_{1}<K_{2}<\cdots$. This is a contradiction since $S$ is finite. Therefore, a maximal subgroup containing $H$ must exist. $\square$

Comment: I think the question is about maximally normal subgroups, which is different from maximal subgroups. (Although the proof of existence of maximal elements in the sublattice of normal subgroups is the exact same. You might as well generalize to arbitrary finite posets, since it is an important perspective to have on the situation, and costs nothing extra.) Small technical point, the way you've defined $S$, it can't be empty since $H\in S$. Also, you can avoid using choice by inducting on the size of the finite poset.

Comment: @whacka31 I do not think that there is a different definition for a normal maximal subgroup. In fact it is true that if $M$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ then either $N_{G}(M)=M$ or $N_{G}(M)=G$, where $N_{G}(M)$ stands for the normalizer of $M$ in $G$. Your observations are correct by the way. I hope that I helped you.

Comment: Please read my answer to see the difference between normal maximal subgroup and maximally normal subgroup. A subgroup can be maximal within the set of proper normal subgroups without being maximal within the full set of proper subgroups. For instance, if $G$ is a nonabelian finite simple group with maximal subgroup $M$, and $H$ is any other finite simple group, then $1\times H$ is maximal *within* the set of proper normal subgroups of $G\times H$ but it is *not* maximal among all proper subgroups since it is properly contained in an actual maximal subgroup $M\times H$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an understandable misreading of the statement. The meaning of

> Let $K$ be a maximal normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$

is: Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$, which is maximal with respect to this property. Informally, "let $K$ be one of the largest among the normal subgroups of $G$ that are contained in $H$". More formally: If $\mathcal S$ denotes the collection of all subgroups of $H$ that are normal in $G$, let $K$ an element of $\mathcal S$ that is maximal with respect to inclusion.